# Convert a data frame in which one column contains array of numbers as string to a json file

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, csvtojson

I'd like to convert a data frame into a json file. One of the columns of the data frame contains time series as a string. Thus, the final json looks like this:

`[{"...":"...","Dauer":"24h","Wertereihe":"8619.0,9130.0,8302.0,8140.0"}, {...}, {...}]`

Is it possible to save the df to a json file in such a way that "Wertereihe" is an array of numbers? This would give: `[{"...":"...","Dauer":"24h","Wertereihe":[8619.0,9130.0,8302.0,8140.0]}, {...}, {...}]`

I used the following snippet to save the df to a json file:
`df.to_json(jsonFile, orient = "records")`

Comment: you need to prepare your JSON file format based on your input dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you need:

```
df['Wertereihe'] = df['Wertereihe'].apply(lambda x: list(map(float, x.split(','))))
df.to_json(jsonFile, orient = "records")
```

Comment: This changes it from a string that contains an array, i.e. "1, 2, 3" to an array of strings, i.e. ["1", "2", "3"]. What I want is "1, 2, 3" ->[1, 2, 3]

Comment: Check my edited answer